# How to specify a different return type based on number of arguments passed to rest parameter function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I create an arrow function with rest parameters that have different return types based on the number of passed arguments?

E.g. I want a `safeId()` that has the following return types:

```
safeId() // () => string
safeId('foo') // (obj: any) => string
safeId('foo', 4, {}, ['hi']) // (...obj: any[]) => string[]

// Currently my return type isn't specific:
const safeId = (...objects: any[]) => string | string[] => {
  // Simplified
  if (objects.length > 1) return sanitizedObjectIds(objects) // string[]
  return 'id'
}
```

Comment: You mean like [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)? I didn't read it thoroughly, but check if [this article](https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/typescript-method-overloading-c256dd63245a) can help you.

Comment: I've attempted overloading but you can't overload with differing number of arguments sadly: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading "the number of parameters should be the same"

Comment: This is not true, or at least, not well explained. You CAN have different number of arguments in the function declarations, you just need to care of all cases in the function implementation.

Comment: I've tried variations of the following:

```
type SafeId = {
  (): string;
  (object: any): string;
  (...objects: any[]): string[];
}

const safeId: SafeId = (...objects: any[]) => {
}
```

But no luck - could you show how you'd do it @StéphaneVeyret?

Comment: I've done it in the answer below. I don't know if it can be done with an arrow function. Give me a few minutes so that I rework it…

Comment: I edited my answer to add a comment for arrow functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare all the forms of your function, and be careful that the implementation can handle all of them:

```js
function safeId(id?: string): string
function safeId(id: string, num: number, ...rest: any[]): string[]
function safeId(...objects: any[]): string | string[] {
  // Simplified
  if (objects.length > 1) return sanitizedObjectIds(objects) // string[]
  return 'id'
}
```

Note that to prevent all ambiguity, I added a 2nd mandatory parameter in the second form of the function. If not, this form would also fit with a single parameter (rest would simply be an empty array).

EDIT: If you want to use arrow function, unfortunately, compiler will complain about the return type. IMHO, this is a bug from *TypeScript*. So, the only way to do it is to disable type check by returning `any`:

```js
type SafeId = {
  (id?: string): string
  (id: string, num: number, ...rest: any[]): string[]
}

const safeId: SafeId = (...objects: any[]): any => {
  // Simplified
  if (objects.length > 1) return sanitizedObjectIds(objects) // string[]
  return 'id'
}
```

Note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38622) for this in *TypeScript* repository.